# make service return value karma jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I trying to test function with service calling
I created `spyOn` in my beforeEach:

```
beforeEach(function () {
      var mockData = {
        data: '123a'
      }
      spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue('mockData');
    });
```

It should be run with my activate function when directive is running, and then call another service with this data
but in every test I have error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Can I somehow get returned value?

Comment: not much familiar with jasmine, but just a suggestion can you try with `returnValue(mockData);`, (remove string marking). since `mockData` is already defined above.

Comment: @anoop, I tried it also, result is the same

Comment: [try this too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24037387/3455035)

Comment: Can you please post the full code of the directive/service which you are trying to test and the whole unit test code